# Segmentation Fault trying to set battery level in android emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am using Android SDK tools on Ubuntu. I have created a Nexus One Virtual Device that uses API-17. I run this emulator which attaches to port 5554.

After this, I connect to this port using telnet, and try to set power level:

```
power capacity 40
```

But, when I do this, I get segmentation and emulator gets killed. Also, when I goto Settings > Battery in emulator, it shows "Battery Status Not Available" and battery is 0%.

[image]

All other commands work, except the power related ones. What should I do?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I just had the same problem and luckily found a solution.

1. Go to your Android Virtual Devices folder. On Windows 7 it's this folder for example:

   `C:\Users\{yourUserName}\.android\avd\{yourAVDName}.avd`
2. Open the **config.ini** file
3. Set the battery option to yes: `hw.battery=yes`
4. **Restart** your **Virtual Device** and be happy :-)

It has been raised as an [issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=39959) already, but I'm not sure why they didn't fix it yet.

Comment: Well, I figured this method already but didn't post the answer. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Strangely, this seems to be a Nexus thing -- my generic device defaulted (properly) to hw.battery = yes