# using telnet crashes android emulator

Tags: android, eclipse, telnet, android-virtual-device

This question [has been asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19453122/android-emulator-got-discharged-completely-running-telnet-power-command-crashi), but none of the answers have worked for me.

I am attempting to use telnet to manipulate the state of an android virtual device, but every time i attempt any command other than `help`, the emulator crashes.  This is happening both in windows and linux.  I have to assume its a problem with the emulator but I have no idea how to solve it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issue and it was solved using the following steps:

1- Close the emulator if it is opened

2- Navigate to the following path:

> C:\Users{yourUserName}.android\avd{yourAVDName}.avd

3- Change the format of the Config.ini file instead of having it as a single line, it should look like this:

> hw.ramSize=343
>
> hw.device.manufacturer=Google
>
> hw.sdCard=yes
>
> hw.mainKeys=yes
>
> hw.accelerometer=yes
>
> skin.name=480x800

4- Make sure that the line hw.battery=YES

5- Start the emulator again

Telnet commands should now work fine.

You can check the following posts:

[Android Emulator got discharged completely - running telnet power command crashing the Emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19453122/android-emulator-got-discharged-completely-running-telnet-power-command-crashi)

and

[Segmentation Fault trying to set battery level in android emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16784882/segmentation-fault-trying-to-set-battery-level-in-android-emulator/17467342#17467342)